# Check if a type is the same as a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a user defined class

```cpp
template<typename T, int N>
class MyClass
{
// Implementation
};
```

and I want to check on the instantiation of another class if its template parameter is an instance of MyClass

```cpp
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_MyClass<T>, bool> = true>
class MapClass
{
// custom stuff here
};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_MyClass<T>, bool> = true>
class MapClass
{
// Some more stuff here
};
```

I tried to implement it like this but my instantiation fails because it requires two parameters. How do I make automatically extract both parameters

```cpp
template <typename T> struct is_MyClass : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, int N> struct is_MyClass<MyClass<T, N>> : std::true_type {};
```

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't partial instantiation work here? Something like `template<typename T> class MapClass<MyClass<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, it does. For some reason, I overcomplicated my problem.

Comment: `std::enable_if` expects a `bool`, not a type, so at least `is_MyClass<T>::value`.

Comment: actually my answer is just what you have already. Is your `is_MyClass` not working?

Comment: oh... I think its just a typo. You used `is_MyClass<T>` whenn you need `is_MyClass<T>::value`

Comment: Yeah, it was the typo + plus I realized that what @iBug suggested was so much simpler and better. I added the is_instance_of* just in case it may be needed at a later date, but for now the partial specialization is cleaner. Cheers for the help.

Comment: "maybe needed at a later date" often turns out as "wtf was this code good for again?!?" at a later date. Better keep things simple and write only the code you actually need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to write a trait `is_instantiation_of_myClass` that uses partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class MyClass {};

template <typename C>
struct is_instantiation_of_myClass : std::false_type {};

template <typename T,int N>
struct is_instantiation_of_myClass<MyClass<T,N>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename C>
constexpr bool is_instantiation_of_myClass_v = is_instantiation_of_myClass<C>::value;
```

Now you can do SFINAE based on `is_instantiation_of_myClass<T>` or just plain specialization:

```
template <typename T,bool = is_instantiation_of_myClass_v<T>>
struct Foo;
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T,true> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T,false> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Foo< int >::value << "\n";
    std::cout << Foo< MyClass<int,42>>::value << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bvacWdofh)